# AT command - Python and Hyperterminal

Tags: android, python, at-command, hyperterminal

I am using commercial Android phone,with that I am able to send AT commands from Hyper-terminal using mobile USB modem port.

```
Is there any possibility to send AT Commands from Python to Hyper-terminal which uses mobile USB modem port?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pywinauto. It will allow you to control hyper terminal from windows.
An other option would be to use [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) to communicate with the serial port directly.